# Create <media:thumbnail> Namespace in DomDocument

Tags: php, rss, domdocument

I am trying to add **< media:thumbnail>** to my RSS Feed but have trouble with adding Attributes like URL, WIDTH, HEIGHT and removing the closing Tag **< /media:thumbnail>**. The Source of the Code is from [here](http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/07/creating-valid-rss-feed-using-php) and I edited for my needs and the  is to be added like explained [here](http://www.rssboard.org/media-rss#media-thumbnails).

```
if($results){ //we have records
    while($row = $results->fetch_object()) //loop through each row
    {
        $item_node = $channel_node->appendChild($xml->createElement("item")); //create a new node called "item"
        $title_node = $item_node->appendChild($xml->createElement("title", $row->cName)); //Add Title under "item"
        $link_node = $item_node->appendChild($xml->createElement("link", "http://www.your-site.com/link/goes/here/")); //add link node under "item"

        $root = $xml->createElementNS('image.png', 'media:thumbnail');
        $root = $xml->appendChild($root);

        //Unique identifier for the item (GUID)
        $guid_link = $xml->createElement("guid", "http://www.your-site.com/link/goes/here/". $row->id);  
        $guid_link->setAttribute("isPermaLink","false");
        $guid_node = $item_node->appendChild($guid_link);

    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
<media:thumbnail xmlns:media="image.png"/>
<media:thumbnail xmlns:media="image.png"/>
<media:thumbnail xmlns:media="image.png"/>
<media:thumbnail xmlns:media="image.png"/>
<media:thumbnail xmlns:media="image.png"/>
<media:thumbnail xmlns:media="image.png"/>
```

The Output should be like below but I cant make anything more because the start is already not working.

```
<media:thumbnail url="http://www.foo.com/keyframe.jpg" width="75" height="50" time="12:05:01.123" />
```

Comment: Could you post a copy of the xml that this snippet actually generates for the rss feed?  Please annotate any diviations from what you expected it to generate.

Comment: The output has been added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have added to the RSS document the namespace attribute that permits media:thumbnail nodes:

```
$rss_node->setAttribute("xmlns:media","http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/")
```

Assumption here is that you used the variable name "$rss_node" to hold the results from calling appendChild to append the rss data to the xml document.

Then for processing of thumbnails from the rows of data pulled from your database.  Replace this:

```
$root = $xml->createElementNS('image.png', 'media:thumbnail');
$root = $xml->appendChild($root);
```

With this:

```
$thumbnail_node = $xml->createElement("media:thumbnail");
$thumbnail_node->setAttribute( "URL", "http://www.foo.com/keyframe.jpg");
$thumbnail_node->setAttribute( "width", "75");
$thumbnail_node->setAttribute( "height", "75" );
$thumbnail_node->setAttribute( "time", "12:05:01.123");
$thumbnail_node = $item_node->appendChild($thumbnail_node);
```

Naturally, change the literal values in the setAttribute to variables or literals that will provide the actual data you want to present.

Here is what this segment actually produces:

```
<media:thumbnail URL="http://www.foo.com/keyframe.jpg" width="75" height="75" time="12:05:01.123"/>
```